# String matching with GREPL and WITH functions in R

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I wish to drop any rows in my data frame which do not meet the regular expression in a specific column i.e the cell must begin with two characters followed by four numbers, after that I do not care if it's U09 or U21. The first 6 characters are all that matters.

I am using the following code but I am getting 0 rows returned and I am not sure why:

```
with(prachData, prachData[grepl("^[A-Z][A-Z][0-9]{4}$", WCEL.name), ])
```

When I type `head(prachData$WCEL.name)` I get the following details:

```
> head(prachData$WCEL.name)
[1] 0           0           CE0001U21B2 CE0001U21A3 CE0001U21C1 CE0001U21B1
13684 Levels: 0 1 11 12 13 2 21 22 23 3 31 32 33 CE0001U09A3 CE0001U09B3 CE0001U09C3 CE0001U21A1 CE0001U21A2 ... WX0114U09C3
```

And using `class(prachData$WCEL.name)` I get:

```
[1] "factor"
```

Can anyone guide me to my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be the use `$` in the pattern which means the end of string as it is a metacharacter, but based on the input showed, that is not the case because after the 4 digits there are other characters as well i.e. the string is not ending with only 6 characters, so `grepl` will return FALSE for the OP's pattern.  Instead it can be,

```
with(prachData, prachData[grepl("^[A-Z][A-Z][0-9]{4}", WCEL.name), ])
```

---

To show a reproducible example

```
v1 <- factor(c(0,           0,           'CE0001U21B2', 'CE0001U21A3', 
                 'CE0001U21C1', 'CE0001U21B1'))
grepl("[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}$", v1)
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

returns all FALSE

So, when we subset 'v1' based on the above index,

```
v1[grepl("[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}$", v1)]
#factor(0)
#Levels: 0 CE0001U21A3 CE0001U21B1 CE0001U21B2 CE0001U21C1
```

it returns a length of 0.

while

```
grepl("[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}", v1)
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun for the detailed explanation. I am using a similar regular expression in another part of my code and this time I wish to add another expression to the end of the with function. This time I have the following code: `AtollInService <- with(Atoll, Atoll[!grepl("[_()]", NOMINAL_ID) & grepl("InService", MILESTONE),!(names(Atoll) %in% atollColDrop),(Atoll, Atoll[grepl("^[A-Z][A-Z][0-9]{4}", THREE_G_CELL_ID),])])` I keep getting an error saying unexpected ',' `!(names(Atoll) %in% atollColDrop),
                                    (Atoll,"` Do I need to replace ',' with an '&'?

Comment: @PigWolf Could you please provide an example.  I think the `Atoll[` part should be outside i.e. `Atoll[withAtoll, !grepl("...`Also, regarding the `,!(names(Atoll`..` are you trying the subset both the rows and columns.

Comment: the first part of my code works as I wish but I am also trying to add a regular expression to the end of the statement to remove any rows that don't meet the regex in column "THREE_G_CELL_ID". My original code is `AtollInService <- with(Atoll, Atoll[!grepl("[_()]", NOMINAL_ID) 
& grepl("InService", MILESTONE) & grepl("^[A-Z][A-Z][0-9]{4}$", NOMINAL_ID) & !grepl("[L18]+[L08]", THREE_G_CELL_ID), !(names(Atoll) %in% atollColDrop)])` I wish to add a regex to this statement to drop rows in column "THREE_G_CELL_ID" that don't begin with [A-Z][A-Z][0-9]{4}.

Comment: @PigWolf Could you post as a new question as it is not that clear from the comments

Comment: Will do, apologies for the poor explanation